# I need to solve the problem of Missing delimiter (. inserted)?

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
{\small
\begin{multline}
\label{eq:kinem}
^{i-1}\mathit{T}_i = \left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos^2\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)+1 \\ 
\sin\phi_i \cos\phi_i (\cos\kappa_i s_i -1) \\ 
\cos\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i\\ 
0 \\
\end{matrix}\right.              
\\
\left
\begin{matrix}
\sin\phi_i \cos\phi_i (\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)&-\cos\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i\\ 
\cos^{2}\phi_i (1-\cos\kappa_i s_i)+\cos\kappa_i s_i& -\sin\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i\\ 
\sin\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i&\cos\kappa_i s_i\\ 
0 & 0\\
\end{matrix}\right.
\\
\left.
\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{\cos\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)}{\kappa_i}\\ 
\dfrac{\sin\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)}{\kappa_i}\\ 
\dfrac{\sin\kappa_i s_i}{\kappa_i}\\ 
1
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{multline}}
```

After running this equation on Overleaf I got the following equation but the error still appeared Missing delimiter (. inserted)[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: in the line with the `\left` command (just this one command) you have forgotten the `.`. like `left.` ... It is just what the error says. But there is no need as far as I see for this `\left` and its `\right.` since they are both ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want brackets, then no need to give `\left`. and `\right`. You have to match your bracket size for starting and ending, for this, I used `\vphantom`, and the codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

{\small
\begin{multline}
\label{eq:kinem}
^{i-1}\mathit{T}_i = \left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos^2\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)+1\vphantom{\dfrac{\cos\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)}{\kappa_i}} \\ 
\sin\phi_i \cos\phi_i (\cos\kappa_i s_i -1) \vphantom{\dfrac{\sin\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)}{\kappa_i}}\\ 
\cos\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i\vphantom{\dfrac{\sin\kappa_i
s_i}{\kappa_i}}\\ 
0 \\
\end{matrix}\right.              
\\
\begin{matrix}
\sin\phi_i \cos\phi_i (\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)&-\cos\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i\\ 
\cos^{2}\phi_i (1-\cos\kappa_i s_i)+\cos\kappa_i s_i& -\sin\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i\\ 
\sin\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i&\cos\kappa_i s_i\\ 
0 & 0\\
\end{matrix}
\\
\left.
\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{\cos\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)}{\kappa_i}\\ 
\dfrac{\sin\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)}{\kappa_i}\\ 
\dfrac{\sin\kappa_i s_i}{\kappa_i}\\ 
1
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{multline}}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As said in my comment, you don't really need the `\left.` (that you forgot the "`.`") and the `\right.` in your middle row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
{\small
\begin{multline}
\label{eq:kinem}
^{i-1}\mathit{T}_i = \left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos^2\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)+1 \\ 
\sin\phi_i \cos\phi_i (\cos\kappa_i s_i -1) \\ 
\cos\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i\\ 
0 \\
\end{matrix}\right.              
\\
\begin{matrix}
\sin\phi_i \cos\phi_i (\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)&-\cos\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i\\ 
\cos^{2}\phi_i (1-\cos\kappa_i s_i)+\cos\kappa_i s_i& -\sin\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i\\ 
\sin\phi_i \sin\kappa_i s_i&\cos\kappa_i s_i\\ 
0 & 0\\
\end{matrix}
\\
\left.
\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{\cos\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)}{\kappa_i}\\ 
\dfrac{\sin\phi_i(\cos\kappa_i s_i -1)}{\kappa_i}\\ 
\dfrac{\sin\kappa_i s_i}{\kappa_i}\\ 
1
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{multline}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]